# Getting the Index of all the nodes connected to a particular Node

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to get all the nodes adjacent to a particular node and store them in a list by traversing. I can't see where I am going wrong in my method (it isn't returning any errors). The method I am having issues with is the `getNodes(int i)` which is at the bottom of the following code:

```
public List<Integer> getNodes(int i){

    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(adjacency[j][i])   {
            list.add(j);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problems, can you please upvote it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your method, You are creating and returning the list from inside the for loop which results in returning the list with just one element or in case of no adjacent it returns null.

Making below changes in your code will return the list with adjacent elements or else if there are none adjacent elements to any node then list will not be null but it will be empty.

```
public List<Integer> getAdjacentNodes(int i)    {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Create 1 instance of List
    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if(adjacencyMatrix[j][i])   {
            list.add(j); // add the adjacent elements in the list.
        }
    }
    return list; // Return the list in the end after all the elements are added in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

The first one, which is causing the problem you mentioned, is the fact that you always return a list with maximum one element.

Here is how you should rewrite the `getAdjacentNodes` function :

```
public List<Integer> getAdjacentNodes(int i)    {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if(adjacencyMatrix[j][i])
            list.add(j);
    }
    return list;
}
```

However, you might also consider testing for `adjacencyMatrix[i][j]`. It is not clear whether your matrix should be symmetric or not, or whether in `getAdjacentNodes` you want to get edges that are in both directions or not.

Other problems in your code :

- same thing about symmetry for `addEdge(int, int)` and `edgeFrom`
- your function `getNodeIndex` is wrong (and also useless)